# Why is there a DNA tag on SO?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

There was a [dna](/questions/tagged/dna) tag added to SO, I really think this tag needs to get booted. Why is it even there? As far as I can tell it's being used for "I have a homework problem mapping DNA sequences."

I understand making tags to help organize questions about [serial-devices](/questions/tagged/serial-devices), or [php](/questions/tagged/php), but the content of a programming problem? What if a user has a homework question about (I don't know) sheep? Do we need a [sheep](/questions/tagged/sheep) tag to categorize all of those as well?

Can we get rid of the [dna](/questions/tagged/dna) tag?

Comment: wow, clicking that tag makes me feel like I've fallen into a parallel universe.

Comment: No sheep, but I can offer you a [turtle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turtle) :-).

Comment: It looks like `helix` gets abused as well....

Comment: Would it make sense to re-tag some of those questions with the `bioinformatics` tag?

Comment: Why not make "dna" a tag synonym of "bioinformatics"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I see three kinds of questions in that tag:

- Homework-type questions about string processing, where the fact that the strings represent DNA is an irrelevant detail. These should be retagged to [string](/questions/tagged/string). Examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495592/dna-to-rna-conversion-java-swing-why-arent-my-jbuttons-working) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569453/c-output-all-possible-dna-kmers-of-a-given-length)
- Bioinformatics questions. DNA sequences tend to be very long, with some typical search operations. There are libraries dedicated to DNA processing. **The tag is meaningful and useful** for these questions. Examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436348/comparing-and-visualising-groups-of-sequences) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237073/finding-splice-sites-from-snp-data-instead-of-sequences)
  There is a [dna-sequence](/questions/tagged/dna-sequence) tag that covers this meaning and that is used more often. After casperOne indiscriminately blazed through the tag, I went back and retagged questions to [dna-sequence](/questions/tagged/dna-sequence) where it seemed appropriate.
- DNA-based computing. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432645/in-dna-computing-what-is-the-analogy-to-a-desktop-or-laptop-computer) It's off-topic.

Comment: Nice job checking up on that mass-destruction operation! (Although I can't see the second example, it's been mod-deleted.)

Comment: There is already [tag:bioinformatics]. Why would [tag:dna] be more appropriate?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Why have [tag:list] when there's already [tag:data-structures]? Why [tag:windows-8] and not just [tag:windows]? Why have tags at all when it's all about [tag:programming] anyway?

Comment: In how many cases is knowing the question is someway about DNA relevant? Does a programming question have a different answer, if it is tagged [tag:dna] (with the actual meaning given to the tag)? [tag:programming] is not a used tag; if it were, it would be too generic.

Answer (score 6):

It does mean something relevant for computing. From Wikipedia:

> Windows DNA is short for Windows Distributed interNet Applications Architecture, a marketing name for a collection of Microsoft technologies that enable the Windows platform and the Internet to work together. Some of the principal technologies comprising DNA include ActiveX, Dynamic HTML (DHTML) and COM. Windows DNA has been largely superseded by the Microsoft .NET Framework, and Microsoft no longer uses the term.

However, it does not seem to be used like that, as the question seem to be just about DNA sequences. I think best burniated and if there was a DNA question tag it windows-dna.

Comment: OK, I'll give you that. But this _clearly_ isn't how the tag is being used

Answer (score -1):

[dna](/questions/tagged/dna) is effectively used to mean *Deoxyribonucleic acid*.
With that meaning, it is not a tag that is needed on Stack Overflow. The fact the question is someway related to the DNA is not so relevant to require a tag, especially because it is used in different contexts (e.g. different programming languages).

The tag can be removed from the post revisions (i.e. burninated), but first somebody should search for questions to close, such as [String read and find different sub-sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993887/string-read-and-find-different-sub-sequences) (which is already closed).